# Using Highcharts and displaying a message over or on the chart when there is no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

I'd like to know if there is a built-in or accepted way to show a label or message over the chart (or where the chart would be) if there are no data series.

I couldn't find anything in the Highcharts docs and I'm trying to stay away from using jQuery (or just JavaScript in general) to check if the result has data and then changing the DOM on my own.

The data is coming in as json from a MVC 3 controller call if that helps or changes anything.

Ideally it would be a message that displays over an empty chart so users know a chart object is there.

Thanks!

Comment: Why avoid javascipt if you are already using json?

Comment: And highcharts is JS based...so, there is that

Comment: I don't think I phrased my question correctly - I'm looking for a Highcharts API that allows me to overlay a message on top of the chart if no data is loaded, or until data is loaded. I don't want to write a one-off jQuery or plain JavaScript function because nobody else on my team writes JS and they might want to change the message.

Comment: try loading options http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#loading

Comment: Strikers: Thanks for the information. Using the loading property and changing the message displayed via the lang object is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Strikers, can you change your comment to an answer so that Josh R can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @JoshR can you show your code for displaying the loading message when a data series is empty. I'm also using json and if a date range is selected that contains no data i'd like to display a custom message. I can do it with jQuery and check the AJAX response but would like to see how you did it. Thanks

Comment: I'm happy to. I have to dig it up after work so it will take me a few hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now an official plugin which shows a 'No Data to Display' message, after the loading message, when there is no data loaded into the chart. I've found it to be quite handy when the user is allowed to select a time range from search and filter form, and no results are returned from the search. It looks much better than having an empty chart.

Here is a link announcing the plugin, and jsfiddle example.

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1065633-display-no-data-to-display